# using CSV to process 2 text files line by line

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have two text files.  One has about ~100 rows (A) and the other could have have ~800 rows (B).

I wish to read a line from A and then read all the lines from B and then print a line which has values from each file.

I'm using python's csv module since these file formats and contents are known to me and they are all comma separated values.

My code looks something like this...

```
import csv

infile1 = r'C:\zData\a.txt'
infile2 = r'C:\zData\b.txt'

csvfile1  = open(infile1, 'r')
myreader1 = csv.DictReader(csvfile1)

csvfile2  = open(infile2, 'r')
myreader2 = csv.DictReader(csvfile2)

for row1 in myreader1:

    for row2 in myreader2:

        print "GID = " + row1['GID'] + ", ABC = " + row2['ABC']
```

I suspect this is a simple problem but for some reason this code reads only the first row of the outer loop (infile1) and all of the rows of the inner loop (infile2).

What am I doing wrong?  I tried adding myreader1.next and this didn't seem to make a difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the a `csv.reader` or `csv.DictReader` object only *once*; then the file pointer is at the end of the file.

You should probably just read all lines from the first file (the smaller one) into a list kept in memory:

```
with  open(infile1, 'r') as csvfile1:
    rows1 = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile1))
```

Now you can loop over that list as many times as you need to:

```
with open(infile2, 'r') as csvfile2:
    myreader2 = csv.DictReader(csvfile2)

    for row1 in myreader2:
        for row2 in rows1:
            print "GID = " + row1['GID'] + ", ABC = " + row2['ABC']
```

The alternative would be to re-open `myreader2` each time inside the loop:

```
with open(infile1, 'r') as csvfile1:
    myreader1 = csv.DictReader(csvfile1)
    for row1 in myreader1:
        with open(infile2, 'r') as csvfile2:
            myreader2 = csv.DictReader(csvfile2)

            for row2 in myreader2:
                print "GID = " + row1['GID'] + ", ABC = " + row2['ABC']
```

If however you need to show matches between the two files, read the first file into a dictionary instead:

```
with  open(infile1, 'r') as csvfile1:
    rows1 = {row['GID']: row for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile1)}
```

Now `rows1` is a dictionary mapping `GID` keys to the row that lists that value. This assumes that each row has a unique `GID` value.

This will make it easy to match rows against information from the second CSV file:

```
with open(infile2, 'r') as csvfile2:
    myreader2 = csv.DictReader(csvfile2)

    for row in myreader2:
        if row['GID'] in rows1:
            print 'Matching GID {}!'.format(row['GID'])
            print 'infile1: {}'.format(rows1[row['GID']])
            print 'infile2: {}'.format(row)
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning the other alternative: Move the `open` and `DictReader` construction for file2 inside the loop. It's probably not what he actually wants (reading the whole thing into a dict, as you suggest, is almost certainly the best solution), but it may be easy for him to understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
f = ["gid={}, abc={}".format(x['gid'],y['abc']) for y in myreader2 for x in myreader1]
print f
```